# My PVC toilet flange is lag bolted to the wood floor. The flange is about 3/8 inch below the floor. Large bolt heads

Tags: toilet, flange

My PVC toilet flange is lag bolted to the wood floor. The flange is about 3/8 inch below the floor. The bolt heads prevent a spacer. This toilet wax double ring has failed at least twice since 1994. I think the large lag bolts may contribute to the problem.
Should I replace flange and bolts? Will I  be able to secure the new flange with the lag bolt holes being bigger? Do you have a better solution?

Comment: do you have a picture of the mess

Comment: Seconded on the request for a picture. We're not a product recommendation SE but I'd be inclined to go to a Better Than Wax or other similar product if the scenario is like I imagine.

Comment: I am new to the site. How do I post a photo?

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/5iFbESTNmgRYhmb68

Comment: Also the pipe immediately turns to the side.

Comment: I think the reducer, (funnel) attaches to the exterior of the bent pipe.